# Grails: Connect to legacy database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to connect to the legacy database. My legacy database is using postgresql. I use db-reverse-engineer plugin to generate the domain class, the generated domain class :

```
class TableLogin {

    String username
    String password
    Integer userLevel

    static mapping = {
        id name: "username", generator: "assigned"
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        username maxSize: 30
        password nullable: true, maxSize: 36
        userLevel nullable: true
    }
}
```

I run `generate-all`, the action list is work fine. But, when i click one of the data/username (to perform the show action), i got this error : TableLogin not found with id null

And I try to trace with this code :

```
    def rowLogin = TableLogin.get("supervisor")
    log.error(rowLogin as JSON)
```

And i got :

```
{"class":"webnico.TableLogin","id":null,"password":"2dcc509a6f7584","userLevel":0,"username":"supervisor"}
```

Why the `id` is null ?
I think because the id is null so the show action doesn't work

---

I update my domain class, become :

```
class TableLogin {

    String id

    String username
    String password
    Integer userLevel

    static mapping = {
        id name: "username", generator: "assigned"
        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        username maxSize: 30
        password nullable: true, maxSize: 36
        userLevel nullable: true
    }

    def afterLoad() {
        id = username
    }
}
```

The `id` is no longer null

```
{"class":"webnico.TableLogin","id":"supervisor","password":"2dcc509a6f7584","userLevel":0,"username":"supervisor"}
```

But, the show action still doesn't work. The show URL seems to be correct, http://mylocalhost.com:9000/webnico/tableLogin/show/supervisor But I still got the same error : TableLogin not found with id null

Is it means we cannot use the scaffold (`generate-all`) when the `id` type is not `Long` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha... the show action doesn't work properly because by default the parameter of show action is Long. So, we need to modify the parameter type become String.

```
    def show(Long id) {
...
    }
```

become

```
    def show(String id) {
...
    }
```

And off course, we need to modify the others action (edit, update, delete) that's need `id` parameter too.